# Why do I have 2 different required field validation popups

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 different pages, each with a form on them.

now one page if I leave a required field empty I get these validation popups:
[image]

This is the code of the image above:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p class="control-label col-md-5"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>Voorletter(s)</b></p>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Voorletters, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", placeholder="K" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Voorletters, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

but on the other I get a popup, which if you ask me has the same code:

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p class="control-label col-md-5"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>Functie</b></p>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Functie1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Functie1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**but I would prefer the latter option, how do I always get that?**

Is the latter validation message a chrome standard?

**EDIT:**

earlier I tried to change the first validation message "This field is required" by making a metaclass, but that only changed the text.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(medewerkerMetaData))]
public partial class medewerker
{
    public partial class medewerkerMetaData
    {
      //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Verplicht invullen!")]
        public string Voorletters { get; set; }

      // more code
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is showing mvc client side validation error from your `[Required]` attribute. The 2nd is showing the browsers HTML-5 validation message (because of the `required` attribute) which means you have not included the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts in that view (or thay are loaded incorrectly ad are not working).

When you use the validation scripts, its adds the `novalidate` attribute to your form so that the HTML-5 validation is ignored (the 2 do not work well together).

Despite what you may think, you do not want the browsers HTML-5 validation - its is client side validation only (not server side which is the most important) and will not match your server side validation attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I just noticed I only have `"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"` in my jsbundle, so I should add the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` to that?

Comment: No, the `*` wildcard will load both. But neither are being loaded in your 2nd case

Comment: strange because they are showing up in the console.

Comment: Then you must be loading them in the wrong order (perhaps you have a copy of `jquery-{version}.js` after those scripts (which wipes them out)

Comment: the `jquery-{version}.js` is being loaded on the _layout page all the way at the top and the `jquery.validate*` at the bottom of the create.cshtml so that's not it either.

Comment: Once more - it means that your scripts are not being loaded correctly!!!

Comment: I'm sorry to annoy you, I understand that they're not being loaded correctly and I don't mean to disagree with you. I'm just sharing information x)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174393/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-fllnangl).

Comment: I fixed it by making partial class of functie and added [Required(ErrorMessage="Verplicht invullen!")] to the string of Functie1. I pretty much said the same in the discussion.